# Unity Soomla Score not updated when Purchase completed successfully

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-billing, unityscript, soomla

I implemented Soomla inn app purchase for android in unity it work fine but my score in not updated when purchase completed successfully what i do.I set the "android.test.purchased" for purchasing. Here is my Code

```
void Start () 
        {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score" ,0)
        }
    void CheckIAP_PurchaseStatus()
       {
            //What I do here ????? below check not working for me
          if (StoreInventory.IsVirtualGoodEquipped ("coinspack_a_item_id"))
            {
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score" , PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score") + 8000);

            }}
        void OnGUI () 
        {
         if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), "Buy"))
            {
             try {
                StoreInventory.BuyItem ("coinspack_a_item_id");                                 
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {   
                  Debug.Log ("SOOMLA/UNITY" + e.Message); 
                    }
                    }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going about it the wrong way. You should really read the SOOMLA documentation. This is a quick YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3u3Q4WEEEkc&list=PLi8OcITs56tOj2ZNOmYRIrBIxkVecodth) that I have put together.

Basically you need to:
1 - Firstly, I would not manage the economy myself if I were you, I would rather let SOOMLA do it. If you have defined a currency pack, then on a successful purchase SOOMLA will automatically top-up your balance.

2 - Otherwise, if you want to do it yourself, then set-up the event handlers that SOOMLA offers and do it inside OnItemPurchased event which is fired after a successful market purchase.

3 - Make sure the Core and Store prefubs are on a Scene/Page that is loaded only once for the entire duration of the game.

4 - If you want to trap errors in the Store then don't do it with a try catch, instead set-up the OnUnexpectedErrorInTheStore event.

Please read the documentation [here](http://know.soom.la/unity/store/), and as a side note, not sure if you knew but SOOMLA have a dedicated support forum at [answers.soom.la](http://answers.soom.la/) where you might get quicker answers.

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions:

- Make sure you listen to the `onSoomlaStoreInitialized` event and start querying the inventory only after that.
- Handle other SOOMLA events that are triggered to indicate a successful purchase.  See here: http://know.soom.la/unity/store/store_events/
- Consider using [SOOMLA LevelUp](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/24613) - it's another open-source package that provides a rich model of worlds, levels, scores, missions, rewards etc.  It also handles storage aspects for you so you don't need to call `PlayerPrefs` yourself.
- Post this question to the SOOMLA forum: http://answers.soom.la/